How to Batch Process Long Documents Exceeding the Google Document AI Page Limit?
I'm working with Google Document AI to process long documents, where the number of pages exceeds the processor limit (~8k pages). The current documented page limit for Enterprise OCR is 500 pages for batch processing, however I am able to successfully process ~2k pages before getting this error:

"status": {
"code": 3,
"message": "Invalid input document content."
}

While I found a method in the Document AI toolbox to create batches for GCS directories containing more files than the processor limit, it doesn't address individual files with too many pages.
Additionally, I discovered a parameter within ProcessOptions for sending a page range. However, this parameter is for online processing only - not batch processing.
I understand I can work around the page limit by manually breaking up my files and then combining the output, but I'm looking for a solution that avoids this additional preprocessing and postprocessing.
Is there a straightforward way to handle batch processing of long documents exceeding the processor page limit without manually splitting and recombining them? Thanks!

Hi @Leo Glowacki,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. do consider accepting and upvoting if it helps, as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research.

Currently as per the gcp documentation Number of pages in active processing is 10k only -  10,000 per project(default value) . That’s why you are getting error number of pages exceeds the processor limit (~10k pages) and  for batch process requests per processor - default value is 5 per project .
Batch processing allows a maximum of 1,000 files per request. If you have more documents to process, then you must divide the documents into multiple batches for processing  .   In  your case you don’t want to break those files or split larger document into smaller parts.
so you can request for Quota Increase via console or you can contact the cloud support team  to increase your quota limit for your project .

Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this doesn't fully answer my question as I'm looking for an automated method to process documents that exceed the batch processing limit for DocumentAI OCR. Also, is the link to the feature request correct? It seems to be for a request to increase the online processing limit to more than 10 pages, which has been done. I've edited my original question to be more clear.

As of now there is no automated method to process documents that exceed the batch processing limit  - you can open a new Feature request  as per requirements on the public issue tracker describing your issue and Eng team will look on the issue for future implementation .
